# How to ignore hyphened words while creating a list in Python?

Tags: python

Very green python user here. I have a .csv file with hundreds of wines, their price and rating, and the wineries that sell a particular wine. I am trying to write a function that returns the number off all the wineries for a given wine, shown below:

```
def all_wineries(wine): 
    wineries = []    
    for i in range(len(csv_data)): 
        if wine.lower() in cell(i, "variety").lower(): 
            wineries.append(cell(i, "winery"))

    return list(set(wineries))

x = all_wineries("Pinot Noir")
len(x)
```

However, I failed to notice that some wines are hyphenated (Ex. "Pinot Noir-Gamay) and those are being included in my final answer. How can I ignore those wines that are not exactly what I type into my function?

Comment: Can you use `wine.lower().strip() == cell(i, "variety").lower().strip()`?

Comment: Can you post a working example? I don't know what `csv_data` or `cell(..)` are.

Comment: If you want exact, test for equality. `if wine.lower() == cell(i, "variety").lower(): `

Comment: As @EdWard notes, using `==` is almost certainly what you want. `in` for `str` is a substring test, so you'll accept anything that contains the string `"Pinot Noir"` (e.g. `"My Pinot Noir"`, `"Pinot Noir the Second"`, `"AllMixedPinot NoirUp"`, etc.), not just things that exactly match that string.

Comment: Side-note: To get repeatable results, I'd suggest changing the `return` to `return sorted(set(wineries))`. Avoid even the `set` conversion by just using a `set` from the get-go, e.g. `wineries = set()`, and `wineries.add(cell(i, "winery"))`, ending with just `return sorted(wineries)`, which avoids storing duplicates at all, and reduces you from storing up to three copies of the data (original `list`, temp `set`, final `list`) in memory at once two just two copies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm elaborating on Ed Ward's comment here.

```
wine.lower().strip() == cell(i, "variety").lower().strip()
```

The lower() function converts the string to lowercase. The strip() function removes any whitespace (spaces, tabs) from the beginning and end of the string.  Use these two functions on both the wine you are looking for and the wine you are looking at. The two wines will only match if they are exactly the same (no hyphens).

```
def all_wineries(wine): 
    wineries = []    
    for i in range(len(csv_data)): 
        if wine.lower().strip() == cell(i, "variety").lower().strip()
            wineries.append(cell(i, "winery"))

    return list(set(wineries))

x = all_wineries("Pinot Noir")
len(x)
```

Comment: That's exactly what I needed. I knew about the strip() method but was unsure if I could use it in this context. Thank you!